# How to update html page for all viewers?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I want to update a page with the name of the last person to submit a form. I have the following code but I can only get it to update on one device. When the page is viewed form another device it doesn't have the updated name.

```
 <form name="leds" id="ledSend" method="get" target="_blank" action="https://agent.electricimp.com/Fk43xPMkSrWF">
Lamp Control: <input type="radio" name="led" value="0" checked>Off
              <input type="radio" name="led" value="1">On<br>
How long should the Lights stay on? <input type="text" name="timer" value="10">seconds<br>
Your name? For Our Records <input id="name" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Your name here"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Update!" onclick="updateTable();"/>

</form>

<p id="last"></p>
<script>
 function updateTable(){
 document.getElementById("last").innerHTML =document.forms['leds'].elements[3].value;
 alert(document.forms['leds'].elements[3].value+", You are about to change the Lights! Beware that      there is about a 30 second delay on the live stream.");
 }
 </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: consider using a database to store the data and ajax to check for updates/process accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use javascript like this (to set a value for an element, for example) you are only changing the value on the one workstation viewing the page.

You would need some kind of datastore on the server that the web browser can push data to and retrieve data from. For example, this could be in-memory on the server (short-term and volatile) or a database management system (long term persistence).